# Optimized SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

**Table Schema**

For the two tables, the CREATE queries are given below:

***Table1:***   (file_path_key, dir_path_key)

> create table Table1(file_path_key varchar(500), dir_path_key
>   varchar(500), primary key(file_path_key)) engine = innodb;

Example, file_path_key = /home/playstation/a.txt
         dir_path_key = /home/playstation/

***Table2:*** (file_path_key, hash_key)

> create table Table2(file_path_key varchar(500) not null, hash_key
>   bigint(20) not null, foreign key (file_path_key) references
>   Table1(file_path_key) on update cascade on delete cascade)
>   engine = innodb;

***Objective*:**

```
Given a hash value *H* and a directory string *D*, I need to find all those 
hashes which equal to *H* from Table2, such that, the corresponding file entry 
doesn't have *D* as it's directory.
```

In this particular case, Table1 has around 40,000 entries and Table2 has 5,000,000 entries, which makes my current query really slow.

> select distinct s1.file_path_key from Table1 as s1 join (select * from                             Table2 where hash_key = H) as s2 on s1.file_path_key = s2.file_path_key and s1.dir_path_key !=D;

Comment: The (potential) size of your key certainly isn't helping.  It doesn't look like you need the potential key range - would you consider switching to an auto-gen primary key that you join on?  This should reduce the size of your table considerably - for one thing, it would mean that `file_path_key` could be turned into just `file` (which would potentially reduce mismatches).  Too bad you're not using an RDBMS that supports recursive CTEs - they work perfectly for folder structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-select is really slowing your query down unnecessarily.

You should remove that and replace it with a simple join, moving pushing all of the non-join related criteria down into the WHERE clause.

Also you should add indexes on the Table1.dir_path_key and Table2.hash_key columns:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
  ADD INDEX dir_path_key dir_path_key(255);

ALTER TABLE Table2
  ADD INDEX hash_key (hash_key);
```

Try something like this for the query:

```
select distinct s1.file_path_key 
from Table1 as s1 
join Table2 as s2 on s1.file_path_key = s2.file_path_key
where s1.dir_path_key !=D
and s2.hash_key =H;
```

Comment: Sure, I'll try this. How do you go about adding an index to a column?

Comment: I added sample DDL for creating the indexes. Beware this will lock the tables for a few minutes so you should not do this on a live production database.

Comment: Well, the tables are not updated once they are filled in my use case. So that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Sorry I'm a little late, but adding indexes worked perfectly! SELECT queries are so much faster now! Thanks Ike!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest selecting entries from Table2 into a temporary table first:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 INTO #Temp WHERE hash_key = H
```

Then join the temporary table in your SELECT statement:

```
select distinct s1.file_path_key from Table1 as s1 join #Temp as s2 on s1.file_path_key = s2.file_path_key and s1.dir_path_key !=D;
```

Comment: Does that make a difference to the query execution time?

Comment: I usually notice a fair difference when I've put this into practise in the past.